# IntelliSense doesn't recognize objects within global_this

Tags: typescript, jestjs, intellisense, javascript-intellisense, jest-puppeteer

I'm trying to deploy the Jest-Puppeteer-example from The Jest documentation [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/puppeteer) on my machine. While the test functions without a problem, IntelliSense does not seem to correctly interpret the `global_this.__BROWSER_GLOBAL__` from `setup.js` as a `Browser` object, neither within the module, nor outside of it, even though it recognizes `global_this` as a module. Other Jest or Puppeteer-related functionality is interpreted correctly by IntelliSense.

Is there a way to have IntelliSense recognize the `global_this.__BROWSER_GLOBAL__` object as a `Browser`-object?

I tried running `npm i @types/puppeteer` before I noticed that it seems to have been a problem with `globalThis`. What I expected from that is that IntelliSense would start working on `global_this.__BROWSER_GLOBAL__`, but it didn't.

I also tried turning the test file into a Typescript file and adding the following to the top of it:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var browser : puppeteer.Browser = globalThis.__BROWSER_GLOBAL__;
```

and replacing the other reference to globalThis.**BROWSER_GLOBAL** with a reference to the browser variable.

This has caused several issues:

1. Within VSCode: `Cannot find namespace 'puppeteer'.`
2. When trying to run the test, Justjs does not recognize the Typescript Syntax and runs into an error.
3. IntelliSense still doesn't give me correct autocompletion on the browser variable.